# I can't find last update on Github repository

Tags: git, github, repository

as you can see in this screenshot from github page. there was an update 7 minutes ago in this repo. but i can't see what was updated. i've searched through all the branches and commits. but found no trace of an update. 
Could someone give me a tip where I can find this update?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you've tried so far and what you're expecting to see? "I can't see what was updated" - What're you doing to accomplish this? "found no trace of an update" - What did you do? etc!

Comment: actually use my repo with two other colleagues quite normal and actually if someone makes a new commit or merge etc. then on github page, according to "updated X mintues/day/year ... age" is displayed. and if I open the repo and search, I will find that. e.g. a file or several files are updated by last commit.  
and in my case i would have expected that something or some file would update itself. but no file has changed before "7 "minutes (regarding screeshot from above). 
and now i would like to know if no file has changed, added or deleted. then what has been updated?

Comment: I have the same painful confusion because I trusted git and github but it's totally obvious that an 8-bit file system from 1984 would cause less damage than git

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, you juste create the repository so there is nothing in it and the "update" is the creation of the repo.

Comment: thank you . But i use this Repo over than one year. a